# What is the best practice to renew Access Token for an API if you are just granted ClientId and ClientSecret and NO Refresh Token?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0

I've spent a past couple weeks or so scouring through .Net Core docs and tutorials and now I'm building my first .Net Core web app. So the app basically consists of pulling data from an online API based on search parameters. Nothing spectacular. Now, my problem lies within OAuth2 the API uses to limit access to its data. It's my first time encountering OAuth2 and working with remote APIs in general, so as you might figure I've spent the last couple days going through OAuth documentation and learning about API consumption. The API I use to fetch data is Amadeus API and the duration of the access token I am granted is 30 minutes. So after banging my head for a couple days and trying to refresh my Access Token by all different kinds of means, I figured Amadeus doesn't even provide Refresh Token and I should basically use ClientId and ClientSecret to renew the access token when it expires or when it's close to expiring. My app doesn't have any user authentication and just serves to get data from the API.

So my questions are:

1) What is the best practice to renew Access Token if you are just granted ClientId and ClientSecret?

2) Is there a way to automate this process by using some in memory data and not relying on 401 response to check if my token has expired?

My guess was trying to use [Outgoing request middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.1#outgoing-request-middleware) to try and access request specific data or data stored in memory like, let's say, the time last Access token was generated and then deciding if I should renew it or not, before sending the request. My problem is I'm not very adept at this and I'm not sure if I can access my HttpClient instance inside this middleware and renew its token with HttpClient.SetBearerToken() method. I've tried using HttpContext as well but I'm not really sure how it works behind the scenes and Microsoft documentation that I've found for it is rather scarce. Thus another question would be:

3) Can I pass HttpContext to a custom middleware like in [this case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-2.2#use-httpcontext-from-middleware) but use it to override a method like SendAsync() and then in conjunction with that, based on the intel I gather, use HttpClient.SetBearerToken() within that same middleware to update my transient HttpClient instance which is generated by HttpClientFactory?

Any help or advice is much appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

> 1) What is the best practice to renew Access Token if you are just
>   granted ClientId and ClientSecret?

You cannot renew an Access Token without a Refresh Token. Your only option is to create a new Access Token which means going back thru the OAuth Authorization Flow.

> 2) Is there a way to automate this process by using some in memory
>   data and not relying on 401 response to check if my token has expired?

If you can hack the memory of a machine, maybe. However, using supported methods that will continue to work today and tomorrow, the answer is no.

> 3) Can I pass HttpContext to a custom middleware like in this case but
>   use it to override a method like SendAsync() and then in conjunction
>   with that, based on the intel I gather, use
>   HttpClient.SetBearerToken() within that same middleware to update my
>   transient HttpClient instance which is generated by HttpClientFactory?

I have no idea. Since the answer to #1 is no, you probably cannot. Note that setting a Bearer token does you no good if the token is expired. Tokens have a signature that you will not be able to defeat unless you have the Private Key or a million CPUs for a million years or a vulnerability/weakness is discovered.

Comment: In regard of #2: Typical OAuth2 clients should provide an expiration value for the access token in the response and in case of a JWT, it is also possible to extract the `exp` claim.

Comment: @Silvermind - Good point. I interpreted the question as trying to bypass OAuth. Reading it again, your view is probably what he was asking.