# How to get an access token django with linkedin api as a variable?

Tags: python, django, api, access-token, linkedin-api

I have been trying to work with the linkedin API for some time now and for whatever reason I'm having some trouble with the access token. I have retrieved my access token through some youtube video where I copied and pasted a url after I logged in, but I am getting the following error when I try and use that access token.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4CMc.png)

I'm not totally sure, but I think I have to call the access token within my program and have as a variable so it doesn't expire, but I'm not sure how to fix that error. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

your variable is not expiring, your access token is. Its controlled from the LinkedIn server.

Not used the LinkedIn API till now, but check if it has some access-token - refresh token mechanism. Basically, a refresh token will allow you to renew your token. Renew tokens are longer lived than access tokens, and are meant for this purpose.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56715472/what-is-the-best-practice-to-renew-access-token-for-an-api-if-you-are-just-grant#:~:text=You%20cannot%20renew%20an%20Access,if%20my%20token%20has%20expired%3F](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56715472/what-is-the-best-practice-to-renew-access-token-for-an-api-if-you-are-just-grant#:%7E:text=You%20cannot%20renew%20an%20Access,if%20my%20token%20has%20expired%3F)